# Angular 2 - Route child component to a different URL

Tags: angular

I have a child component that routes to /home/activity but I want to route to /activity instead but it would still be able to keep the parent component. What do I put in my app.module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this route to load it on same url ,

```
export const ROUTES: Routes = [
    { 
      path : 'activity' , component : HomeComponent ,  children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ActivityComponent
      }
      ]
    }];
```

This will load first `HomeComponent` on `/activity` and then loads `ActivityComponent` inside the `router-outlet` of `HomeComponent`.